# Params passed to variadic function via function pointer change their value

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have a class with some static functions and a map that contains pointers to these functions:

```
class Conditions
{
    using cbType = bool(*)();
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, cbType> const m_FunctionMap;

    static bool Equal_int(const int A, const int B) { return A == B; }
    static bool Equal_float(const float A, const float B) { return A == B; }
    static bool Greater_int(const int A, const int B) { return A > B; }
    static bool Greater_float(const float A, const float B) { return A > B; }
    static bool Between_int(const int A, const int B, const int C) { return A > B && A < C; }
    static bool Between_float(const float A, const float B, const float C) { return A > B && A < C; }
};
```

Thus, the static functions can have different numbers of parameters with different types. In the .cpp file I am initializing that map:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Conditions::cbType> const Conditions::m_FunctionMap
{
    { "Equal_int", MakeMapVal(&Equal_int) },
    { "Equal_float", MakeMapVal(&Equal_float) },
    { "Greater_int", MakeMapVal(&Greater_int) },
    { "Greater_float", MakeMapVal(&Greater_int) },
    { "Between_int", MakeMapVal(&Between_int) },
    { "Between_float", MakeMapVal(&Between_float) },
};
```

Then I added a method to the class `Conditions` to call these static functions by their name:

```
    template <typename ... argsType>
    static bool Call(std::string const& Key, argsType&& ... Args)
    {
        using prototype = bool(*)(argsType ...);
        return reinterpret_cast<prototype>(m_FunctionMap.at(Key))(Args ...);
        //return reinterpret_cast<prototype>(m_FunctionMap.at(Key))(std::forward<argsType>(Args) ...);  // this has the same issue
    }
```

Now when I run this code, call the `Call(std::string const& Key, argsType&& ... Args)` method that correctly calls the respective static function. For example:

```
Call("Greater_int", 42, 40);
```

However, within the `Greater_int()` function those two parameters are not 42 and 40 any more, but some random values. But in the `Call` function those values are correctly `42` and `40`. Thuse those values change when calling the function pointers via `reinterpret_cast`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I haven't dug in, but what's likely to be missing is the usage of `std::decay`. Overall, this is not a good programming practice. Extremely type-unsafe, and error prone. With a properly-designed class hierarchy, something like that shouldn't even compile, unless all the types are correct. You should rethink your approach completely, for whatever problem you're trying to solve, and try to figure out a completely type-safe solution.

Comment: [Following @SamVarshavchik 's comment] And to this end, I suggest you edit your question to state the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the wilderness of undefined behavior. Your `reinterpret_cast` is casting from unrelated types, and this is just  bad. Remove the cast and make compiler happy some other way.

Comment: Ok, I have these static functions, which all return `bool`. I need to call these by some name/key, but at runtime, they are read-in from a text file (like a small script). They have different number of paramteres of different type. How else can I solve that, if not via function pointers as I did?

Comment: You will have to make sure all those functions have the same signature (for example, accepting some sort of a variant object), than use a pointer to this type, populate the variant with your data and call function. Basically, there should be no reinterpret_cast in your code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misundersdtanding, you want to create a DSL that allows parsing and comparison of dissimilar types.

This can be done very easily with `boost::variant`. It's just some boilerplate and a matter of defining the comparison operations of the dissimilar types.

Small but complete example:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// define the concept of equality in my scripting language
struct is_equal : boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
    // x == x is easy
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const {
        return l == r;
    }

    // define the concept of comparing strings to integers
    bool operator()(const std::string& l, const int& r) const {
        return l == std::to_string(r);
    }

    // and integers to strings
    bool operator()(const int& l, const std::string& r) const {
        return (*this)(r, l);
    }
};

struct is_less : boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
    // x == x is easy
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const {
        return l < r;
    }

    // define the concept of comparing strings to integers
    bool operator()(const std::string& l, const int& r) const {
        return l < std::to_string(r);
    }

    // and integers to strings
    bool operator()(const int& l, const std::string& r) const {
        return (*this)(r, l);
    }
};

struct emit : boost::static_visitor<std::ostream&>
{
    emit(std::ostream& os) : os_(os) {}

    // x == x is easy
    template<class T>
    std::ostream& operator()(const T& l) const {
        return os_ << l;
    }

    std::ostream& operator()(const std::string& s) const {
        return os_ << std::quoted(s);
    }

    std::ostream& os_;
};

struct scriptable_value
: boost::less_than_comparable<scriptable_value>
, boost::equality_comparable<scriptable_value>
{
    using variant_type = boost::variant<std::string, int>;

    scriptable_value(std::string v) : variant_(std::move(v)) {}
    scriptable_value(int v) : variant_(v) {}

    variant_type const& as_variant() const {
        return variant_;
    }

private:
    variant_type variant_;
};

bool operator==(scriptable_value const& l, scriptable_value const& r)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor(is_equal(), l.as_variant(), r.as_variant());
}

bool operator<(scriptable_value const& l, scriptable_value const& r)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor(is_less(), l.as_variant(), r.as_variant());
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, scriptable_value const& r)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor(emit(os), r.as_variant());
}


int main()
{
    auto x = scriptable_value(10);
    auto y = scriptable_value("10");
    auto x2 = scriptable_value(9);
    auto y2 = scriptable_value("9");

    std::cout << x << " == " << y << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x == y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " != " << y << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x != y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " == " << y2 << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x == y2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " != " << y2 << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x != y2) << std::endl;

    std::cout << x << " <  " << y << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x < y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " >= " << y << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x >= y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " <  " << y2 << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x < y2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " >= " << y2 << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x >= y2) << std::endl;

    std::cout << x << " == " << x2 << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x == x2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " != " << x2 << " : " << std::boolalpha << (x != x2) << std::endl;

}
```

expected output:

```
10 == "10" : true
10 != "10" : false
10 == "9" : false
10 != "9" : true
10 <  "10" : false
10 >= "10" : true
10 <  "9" : false
10 >= "9" : true
10 == 9 : false
10 != 9 : true
```